# Regex to find words that start with /u/

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for a regex that starts with /u/. I tried the following query:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(message, "(\\//u/\\w+) ");
```

but it doesn't seem to work. I think it has to do with the slashes?

Example of what the query should do:

"Hello I am /u/myself" -> "/u/myself"
however "Hello I am /u/" should returns nothing

Comment: No need to escape them - `@"(/u/\w+) "`.

Comment: I doubt you really want the space at the end.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. However this one works `@"(?<!\w)/u/\w+"`

Comment: But what are the requirements? You ask about escaping, but what is the real problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(message, @"/u/.+");
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. `@"(?<!\w)/u/\w+"` seems to work perfectly

Comment: But it seems that `/u/\w+` is enough. Well, given your examples, at least.

Comment: What is the main difference?

Comment: `(?<!\w)/` is using a negative lookbehind --> No wordcharacter before the `/`. It works because your examples have a space before it, which isn't a wordcharacter. So `(?<=[ ])/` would give the same results on those examples. Wiktor's advice would also match it in "Iam/u/also"